# realm data base in tableVC

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I'm using Realm database and every time I run a project I have a wanted result with all needed data but not in my tableViewController.
So, here' s fragments of my code :

```
var realmDay:Day = Day()
let dateInFormat = selectedDate.toString()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date = %@", dateInFormat!)
let DaysFromRealmWithFilter = realm.objects(Day.self).filter(predicate)

if(DaysFromRealmWithFilter.count != 0){
    realmDay = DaysFromRealmWithFilter.first!
}
```

and TableVC :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var realmDayToFill:Day = Day()
if(realmDayToFill.lessons.count != 0){
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell        
    cell.titleCell.text = realmDayToFill.lessons[indexPath.item].discipline    
}
```

How to deal with it?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. How to deal with what?

Comment: Agree with @Michael that your question isn't clear enough to provide an answer. However, you may refer to the TableView and GroupedTableView examples that Realm provides for reference: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples